# If all roots of equation $z^4+az^3+bz^2+cz+d=0\;(a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R)$ are of unit modulus, then which of the following is/are correct

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

If all roots of equation $z^4+az^3+bz^2+cz+d=0\;(a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R)$ are of unit modulus, then

(A) $|a|\leq4$

(B) $|b|\leq4$

(c) $|b|\leq6$

(d) $|c|\leq4$

**Solution given in book:**

$z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4=-a\; \implies |a|\leq |z_1|+|z_2|+|z_3|+|z_4| = 4$

$z_1z_2+z_1z_3+z_1z_4+z_2z_3+z_2z_4+z_3z_4 = |b|\; \implies b\leq |z_1z_2|+|z_1z_3|+|z_1z_4|+|z_2z_3|+|z_2z_4|+|z_3z_4|=6$

**My Doubt:** How can be assured that $|b|\leq4$ is false? How can i tell someone this upper bound does not exist?

**My Thought:** All the roots of given polynomial Lies on $|z|=1$

Also is there any other approach to solve this problem for a high school student.

Comment: I think that the point is that $|b|$ could be less than $4$. However you can find an example where $|b|$ is greater than $4$. Nevertheless, $|b|\le6$. So I would say that $(B)$ is generally false and $(C)$ is always true.

Comment: $x^4-4x^3\color{blue}{+6x^2}-4x+1=0.$

Comment: Hint on how to find a counterexample yourself. In the proof, the only estimation used is the triangle inequality. So think about what roots would make the triangle inequality an equality. This leads directly to the counterexample given by the others, i.e. $(z-1)^4$, which shows that the bound is tight.

Comment: I don't ant to bump the question needlessly, but if you have the chance to edit, could you please remove the `complex-geometry` tag? (The `geometry` tag is appropriate.)

Answer (score 5):

You do not *always* have $|b|>4$, but you *may* have that condition and therefore you cannot be sure that (B) will hold. Your calculations show that in fact $|b|\le6$ is a sure thing, but not $|b|\le4$. Only the "sure thing" results, which are all the given ones *except* (B), can be included in a correct inference.

The equation

$x^4-4x^3+6x^2-4x+1=(x-1)^4=0$

has a quadruple root at $1$, and we see $b=6$ which has a larger absolute value than $4$. For an example with distinct (complex conjugate) roots, use

$x^4-3x^3+(38/9)x^2-3x+1=[x^2-(4/3)x+1][x^2-(5/3)x+1]=0,$

where $b$ again exceeds $+4$ and each of the two given quadratic factors has its own pair of complex conjugate roots.

Answer (score 1):

Real coefficients guarantee complex roots only appear in conjugate pairs. Combined with Euler's Formula, the range of trigonometric functions can be used to find all possible values of the coefficients. Other techniques need to be used when there are real roots.

$(z-e^{i\theta})(z-e^{-i\theta})(z-e^{i\alpha})(z-e^{-i\alpha})$

$=(z^2-ze^{-i\theta}-ze^{i\theta}+1)(z^2-ze^{-i\alpha}-ze^{i\alpha}+1)$

$=(z^2-2z\cos \theta +1)(z^2-2z\cos \alpha +1)$

$=z^4-2z^3\cos \alpha +z^2-2z^3\cos\theta+4z^2\cos\theta \cos \alpha-2z\cos \theta+z^2-2z\cos\alpha +1$

$0=z^4-2z^3(\cos \alpha +\cos \theta)+2z^2(1+2\cos\theta\cos\alpha)-2z(\cos \theta + \cos \alpha)+1$

$a=c=-2(\cos \theta + \cos \alpha)$

$b=2+4\cos\theta\cos \alpha$

$|a|=|c|\le 4$

$-2\le b \le 6\implies |b|\le 6$

Comment: That works if all roots are non-real complex, but you still have to treat the case of real roots separately.

Comment: Good point,  @dxiv. I have to break it down into cases.